# Hyperlink a word instead of "goto" symbol in beamer

Tags: beamer

I want to make a beamer presentation and use hyperlinks between pages (in case that someone asks for more details). Generally, I know the procedure that is commonly followed (*see* example below). Yet, I don't feel satisfied with that way (stylised buttons are OK, but sometimes they are too much, especially when you use many in one page). To be more precise, instead of having the "here" button, I want a word to be the hyperlink itself. For example in the following case, I prefer the word "recoded" to be used as a hyperlink.

I hope this makes sense.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames,11pt,mathserif]{beamer} 
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}   
\usepackage{etoolbox}               
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}   
\usecolortheme{rose}     
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\usepackage{appendix}


\author{PSK} 
\title[title]{my title} 
\institute[OSU]{The Ohio State University} 

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}[label = Dependent variables]{Dependent variables}
In order to study how the characteristics of Europeans shape their attitude towards immigrants I use the following questions after \textcolor{purple}{recoding} (\hyperlink{recoding}{\beamergotobutton{here}}).

\end{frame}


\appendix


\section*{Appendix}

\begin{frame}[label = recoding]
\begin{center}
{\small
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline Question & Initial Values  & Dichotomous \\ 
\hline \textcolor{purple}{$\alpha$)} & 1 strongly agree to 5 strongly disagree  & 1 if choice 1 and 2 \\ 
\hline $\beta$) & 1 strongly agree to 10 strongly disagree & 1 if choice 1 to 5 \\ 
\hline $\gamma$) & 1 strongly agree to 10 strongly disagree & -//-  \\ 
\hline $\delta$) & 1 strongly agree to 10 strongly disagree & -//- \\ 
\hline $\varepsilon$) & 1 strongly agree to 10 strongly disagree & -//- \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular} 
}
\end{center}

Back to \hyperlink{Dependent variables}{\beamergotobutton{main}}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: If you don't want the beamer buttons, just use `\hyperlink{recoding}{recoded}`

Comment: Also, please see [this answer on meta.TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225/18228) on some good practices of writing MWEs. Your current minimal working example is not really *minimal* `:)`

Comment: @KevinC Thanks mate, it worked like a charm! It think now it is actually a "minimal" working example.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The syntax of the `\hyperlink` command is

```
\hyperlink{<label>}{<link text>}
```

In your example `<link text>` is made into a Beamer "goto" button by `\beamergotobutton{<link text}`. If you don't want the Beamer buttons, just use `\hyperlink` without the Beamer button commands.

---

P.S. There are several Beamer buttons, in case you might want them back one day:

[image]