# how hyperlink work with \pause{}

Tags: beamer, hyperref, cross-referencing, hyperlink

I would like to set the [hyperlink](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140623/hyperlink-a-word-instead-of-goto-symbol-in-beamer) after the pause. How to get around with this? Many thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames,11pt,mathserif]{beamer} 
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}   
\usepackage{etoolbox}               
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}   
\usecolortheme{rose}     
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\usepackage{appendix}


\author{PSK} 
\title[title]{my title} 
\institute[OSU]{The Ohio State University} 

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}[label = Dependent variables]{Dependent variables}
    \begin{itemize}
        
\item  In order to study how the characteristics of Europeans shape their attitude towards immigrants I use the following questions after %\textcolor{purple}{recoding} (\hyperlink{recoding}{\beamergotobutton{here}}).

\pause
\item \textcolor{purple}{recoding} (\hyperlink{recoding}{\beamergotobutton{here}}).
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\appendix


\section*{Appendix}

\begin{frame}[label = recoding]
\begin{center}
{\small
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline Question & Initial Values  & Dichotomous \\ 
\hline \textcolor{purple}{$\alpha$)} & 1 strongly agree to 5 strongly disagree  & 1 if choice 1 and 2 \\ 
\hline $\beta$) & 1 strongly agree to 10 strongly disagree & 1 if choice 1 to 5 \\ 
\hline $\gamma$) & 1 strongly agree to 10 strongly disagree & -//-  \\ 
\hline $\delta$) & 1 strongly agree to 10 strongly disagree & -//- \\ 
\hline $\varepsilon$) & 1 strongly agree to 10 strongly disagree & -//- \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular} 
}
\end{center}

Back to \hyperlink{Dependent variables}{\beamergotobutton{main}}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Sounds like you should read https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/517992/beamer-hyperlink-to-specific-slide-in-frame-with-specific-after-pause-on-the-sl, even though the only answer has a score of –2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can link to a specific overlay within the frame with `labelname<2>`:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames,11pt,mathserif]{beamer} 
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}   
\usepackage{etoolbox}               
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}   
\usecolortheme{rose}     
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\usepackage{appendix}


\author{PSK} 
\title[title]{my title} 
\institute[OSU]{The Ohio State University} 

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}[label = Dependentvariables]{Dependent variables}
    \begin{itemize}
        
\item  In order to study how the characteristics of Europeans shape their attitude towards immigrants I use the following questions after %\textcolor{purple}{recoding} (\hyperlink{recoding}{\beamergotobutton{here}}).

\pause
\item \textcolor{purple}{recoding} (\hyperlink{recoding}{\beamergotobutton{here}}).
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\appendix


\section*{Appendix}

\begin{frame}[label = recoding]
\begin{center}
{\small
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline Question & Initial Values  & Dichotomous \\ 
\hline \textcolor{purple}{$\alpha$)} & 1 strongly agree to 5 strongly disagree  & 1 if choice 1 and 2 \\ 
\hline $\beta$) & 1 strongly agree to 10 strongly disagree & 1 if choice 1 to 5 \\ 
\hline $\gamma$) & 1 strongly agree to 10 strongly disagree & -//-  \\ 
\hline $\delta$) & 1 strongly agree to 10 strongly disagree & -//- \\ 
\hline $\varepsilon$) & 1 strongly agree to 10 strongly disagree & -//- \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular} 
}
\end{center}

Back to \hyperlink{Dependentvariables<2>}{\beamergotobutton{main}}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```